# (Shiny R) How to dynamically generate multiple outputs in the UI?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I would like to render a varying number of plots depending on the data. Can I access the data from the ui to dynamically generate multiple `plotOutput` calls based on the data?

For example if we have this code:

```
shinyApp(
  ui <- fluidPage(
    lapply(WHAT I WANT TO ACCESS, function(patient) {
      fluidRow(column(1, tags$p(patient)), 
               column(11, lapply(unique(newDT[pat == patient]$clinic), 
                  function(clinic){
                    fluidRow(column(1, tags$p(clinic)),
                             column(10, plotOutput(outputId = paste(patient, clinic), height = "100%")))
                  })))

    })
  ),

  server <- function(input, output) {

    newDT2 <- reactive({
      newDT[dx.x == input$dx]
    })

    #WHAT I WANT TO ACCESS IN UI
    pats <- unique(newDT2()$pat)

    x <-reactive({max(newDT2()$dat) +0.5})
    #observe({print(x())})

    PLOT 
    })
      }
    })
    }
  }
  )
```

However, I cannot access the data frame in the ui like I can in the server. Are there any getarounds?

TIA!

Answer (score 0):

You need to do all of your processing of the data in the `server` and return the output to the `ui`.

In your example, you would place the `lapply` call in the server in a `renderUI` call and put a `uiOutput` in its place in the `ui`.

Here's an example from a shiny app of mine.

In the server:

```
    # dynamically creates a numeric input for each activity in the activities table
    # for the PAL helper panel
    output$activityList <- renderUI({
        act <- split(as.character(activities[order(activities$Sort, activities$Activity), 
                                             "Activity"]), 
                     cut2(1:nrow(activities), g=3))
        div(class = "sidebyside", 
            fluidRow(column(4,lapply(as.character(act[[1]]), 
                           function(x) {numericInput(x,x, value = 0, step=0.5, min = 0)})),
                     column(4,lapply(as.character(act[[2]]), 
                           function(x) {numericInput(x,x, value = 0, step=0.5, min = 0)})),
                     column(4,lapply(as.character(act[[3]]), 
                           function(x) {numericInput(x,x, value = 0, step=0.5, min = 0)}))
                     )
        )

})
```

And in the ui:

```
    uiOutput("activityList")
```